# Alternative proof of the generalized associative law for groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, induction, alternative-proof

The generalized associative law for groups claims that the value of  $a_1\star a_2\star ... \star a_n$ is independent of how it is bracketed, where the symbols denote the usual notations of group theory.

While attempting a proof on my own, I discovered a method that seems right to me but does not appear anywhere as a standard proof. Please comment on the validity of this proof, since it is likely I messed up somewhere.

Throughout the proof we consider elements belonging to a group $G$.

We attempt a proof by induction on the number of elements in the expression. The base cases of 1,2,3 are seen to be true trivially or by the associative property. **Now assume that the value of any n-element expression is independent of how the expression is bracketed. (Induction Hypothesis)**

Now consider any $(n+1)$-element expression given by $a_1\star a_2\star ... \star a_n\star a_{n+1}$. All bracketings of this expression may be divided into $n$ types as follows (these types are **not necessarily disjoint**):

1. bracketings containing $(a_1\star a_2)$

2. bracketings containing $(a_2\star a_3)$
   . 
   . 
   .

n. bracketings containing $(a_n\star a_{n+1})$

Let $(a_i\star a_{i+1})$ = $a_{(i,i+1)}$, which is also an element of $G$ (where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $n$).
Now for any type $i$ considered above, the corresponding $(n+1)$ - element expression can be reduced to an $n$ - element expression by substituting $a_{(i,i+1)}$ instead of $(a_i\star a_{i+1})$. Then by IH, all bracketings of this type evaluate to a bracketing- independent value which we shall call $A_i$.

It remains to show that $A_1 = A_2 = A_3 = .... = A_n$.

But note that for any $i$, 
$A_i$ = $(..((a_1\star a_2)\star a_3)..\star a_{i-1}) \star ((a_{i}\star a_{i+1})\star a_{i+2})\star(..((a_{i+3}\star a_{i+4})\star a_{i+5})..\star a_{n+1})$ = $(..((a_1\star a_2)\star a_3)..\star a_{i-1}) \star (a_{i}\star( a_{i+1}\star a_{i+2}))\star(..((a_{i+3}\star a_{i+4})\star a_{i+5})..\star a_{n+1})$ = $A_{i+1}$.

So for all $i$ from $1$ to $n$, $A_i$ = $A_{i+1}$. This implies
$A_1 = A_2 = A_3 = .... = A_n$, as required. This proves the result for the case of $n+1$. The result is then true by induction for all natural $n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you. I modified my post

Comment: I don't understand this proof. First, you say that two adjacent elements must be bracketed together. Fine. Then you say that any bracketing is "equivalent" to such a bracketing. Why equivalent? (What does that even mean?) It IS such a bracketing, as you just claimed! Anyway, not a big problem, just redundant.

You then consider the case when $a_1$ and $a_2$ are bracketed together. But you never consider cases when they are not. (Which can occur.) Even in this case, you assume that $((a_1a_2)a_3)$ appears, which is not necessarily true, what about for example $(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4)$?

Comment: What I meant was that any bracketing in which no two adjacent elements are explicitly bracketed together is equivalent (equal in value and the placing of other brackets) to a bracketing in which some two adjacent elements ARE bracketed together (because any simplification of the expression must start with some two adjacent terms being "multiplied"). If $a_1$ and $a_2$ are not together, there must be some two adjacent elements that ARE bracketed together. In the last part I show that all bracketings where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are together are equal to ones in which $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ are together.

Comment: $((a_1a_2)a_3)$ is part of an expression in which $a_1$ and $a_2$ are bracketed together, which is an n-element expression and so by my induction hypothesis is equal to any expression in which $a_1$ and $a_2$ are bracketed together. I believe I have shown that bracketings of $a_1$ and $a_2$ are equal to bracketings of $a_2$ and $a_3$ which are then equal to bracketings of $a_3$ and $a_4$ and so on for all adjacent elements (refer last part of proof). I'm sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: Most of my comments still apply. For example, you have proved that, in any bracketing, two adjacent elements are bracketed together. Yet, both in your main post and your latest comment, you consider the case where "no two adjacent elements are bracketed together", a case you just explained does not even occur. The whole proof is similarly confused IMO. In fact, I wouldn't really call it a proof.

Comment: The fact that any bracketing of the expression must include a bracket containing two adjacent elements is trivially seen to be true and should have been omitted anyway. My bad. I still don't see a mistake in the way I use the induction hypothesis, how the "product" of two adjacent elements can be considered a single element in order to reduce the n+1 case to an n-element product and how the associative property can be used to equate expressions in which different adjacent elements are bracketed.

Comment: How about having another go at it, editing your post with my comments in mind?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The original post has been edited.

Comment: Knock Knock Knock

Comment: In the last para there are too many "proceeding similarly" and "and so on". You need a proper induction here as well to complete your proof.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I edited my post to include more details in the last para. I understand that the proof has not been presented formally, but I don't see a flaw in the reasoning of the induction. Could you specifically point out any mistake you spotted?

Comment: Your 'proof' boils down to the statement that you can move from any bracketing of $n$ terms to any other bracketing of $n$ terms by successive applications of associativity. This is true (it is equivalent to generalized associativity) but you do not show it. For example, you cannot deal with $((ab)(cd))e$ using your method, because $(ab)$ is not bracketed with a single other term, but another bracket.

Comment: $((ab)(cd))e$ can be dealt with using the induction hypothesis for $n=4$. Suppose $ab = t$, which reduces the expression to $(t(cd))e$. Since this is a bracketing of $tcde$, by the induction step, it is equal to any other bracketing of $tcde$, specifically, it is equal to $((tc)d)e$. But $((tc)d)e = (((ab)c)d)e = ((a(bc))d)e$ (the second equality comes from the ordinary associative law), and so $((ab)(cd))e = ((a(bc))d)e$. This allows us to switch to a different bracketing. I am not simply using "successive applications of associativity" but also the induction hypothesis.

Comment: You will be able to do every special case because the result is true. But your above 'proof' does not prove each of these special cases, or at least I am not convinced that it does. And: "I am not simply using "successive applications of associativity" but also the induction hypothesis." Literally you are, because your IH uses successive applications of associativity. IH = successive applications. That's a general statement.

Comment: "You will be able to do every special case because the result is true". This is a little confusing. Are you saying that I've assumed the truth of the result before proving it? I only assume its truth for n elements and prove for (n+1), which is what induction does usually. And "You will be able to do every special case" vs "does not prove each of these special cases" suggests that "doing" and "proving" are different somehow?

Comment: By refusing to write out all the steps you are concealing a possible gap in your proof. Just saying "we may use another induction here" isn't enough. These inductions may be different depending on the "shape" of the product. Write down explicitly what your inductive hypothesis is, and write out the proof.

Comment: @RuwimalPathiraja I say 'I think your general argument above does not prove all cases. One possible case is x'. You say 'x is also true, because of <different argument>.' This means that x is true. It does not mean that your original argument proves x.

Comment: I rewrote the proof in a different way. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: I think that the question would be greatly improved if you did three things: (i) write down clearly what it means to "bracket" a string; (ii) write down explicitly what proposition $P(n)$ you are proving by induction; (iii) write your proof without any use of "$\dots$".

Comment: @ancientmathematician The following is an excerpt from Dummit and Foote’s Abstract Algebra (page 18):
“for any $a_1 , a_2, .. , a_n$ in G the value of $a_1\star a_2\star ... \star a_n$ is independent of how
the expression is bracketed (this is called the generalized associative law).”
And on page 19 the induction hypothesis is stated as:
“Next assume for any $k<n$ that any bracketing of a product of  $k$ elements, $b_1\star b_2\star ... \star b_k$ can be reduced (without altering the value of the product) to
an expression of the form
$b_1\star(b_2\star(b_3\star(...\star b_k))...)$”.

Comment: @ancientmathematician If a standard textbook finds it suitable to use the same terms and language (“bracketing”, induction hypothesis, use of “…”) , I don’t see why you should find them so mysterious.

Comment: Thanks. I think the IH should make clear it is being assumed for every choice of the $b_i$, not just for $b_1,b_2, \dots, b_k$. And a bit disappointing that the issue of what we mean by bracketting  is not tackled - until you clarify that it is  not even clear that one of your products of adjacent elements even exists. BTW congratz on exploring this alternative proof!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks OK to me, apart from a couple of typos in the big formula showing $A_i=A_{i+1}$. That formula has an unintended "=" at the end of the first line, and it has "$=A_{i+1}$" at the end of the next-to-last line whereas it should be at the end of the last line.

I think what confused some of the commenters is that you're using $A_i$ initially to denote any of numerous bracketings, and you prove later that they're all equivalent. Let me write out a version of your proof intended to un-confuse that point.

Let $C_i$ be the class of those bracketings of $n+1$ factors in which $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ are bracketed together. (In the tree picture, this means that those two leaves have the same immediate predecessor.) These bracketings can be viewed as bracketings of $n$ factors, by treating the combination $(a_i*a_{i+1})$ as a single factor. (Chop those two leaves off the tree but retain their predecessor.)  By induction hypothesis, all of the bracketings in $C_i$ are equivalent, meaning their equality is provable from the associative law.

So to complete the proof of the generalized associative law, it suffices to show that some bracketing in $C_i$ is equivalent to some bracketing in $C_{i+1}$. For this purpose, use a bracketing in $C_i$ that contains the segment $((a_i*a_{i+1})*a_{i+2})$ and the bracketing in $C_{i+1}$ that is the same except for changing that one segment to $(a_i*(a_{i+1}*a_{i+2}))$. These are equivalent because the only change was one application of the associative law.

I claim that this is a proof, that the commenters would accept it as a proof, and that it's really the same as your proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply! This is indeed what I was trying to say. The original post was edited many times and rewritten once with the help of the commenters' suggestions. I think one of the objections of @ancientmathematician was that "bracketing" needs to be explicitly defined.

Comment: @RuwimalPathiraja Indeed, a systematic development of this material would need a definition of "bracketing" or at least an axiomatic specification of the basic facts about bracketings that can be assumed. But in most contexts, one can assume that these things are understood, just as one assumes the basic facts about real numbers, without giving the definition or axioms. Of course, if it turned out that people disagreed about what bracketings are, then one would have to specify such information explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

What we *know* is that for any 3 elements $a,b,c \in G$ we have $(a * b) * c = a  * (b * c)$.

What we want to *show* is that given any two binary trees with the same elements of $G$ in order at the leaves, e.g:

```
    /\                /\
   / \               / /\
  /\  \             / / /\
 /\ \ /\           / / / /\
a b c d e     and a b c d e
```

that they map to equal expressions when you replace branching with $*$. These trees map to $((a*b)*c)*(d*e)$ and $(a*(b*(c*(d*e)))$

We are all familiar with induction on the natural numbers, but to prove the generalized associativity you will need to use induction on trees.

Comment: The last sentence is false, the result is provable by a suitable induction on natural numbers. Which isn't to say that structural induction isn't a good idea.

Comment: @ancientmathematician would you be able to demonstrate this?

Comment: Yes, any structural induction can be re-written (less clearly) using inductions on the natural numbers.